# Games and Phonegap = cheatable?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm developping a very basic game for android using phonegap.
Since most of the code is Javascript, the game is pretty easy to "hack" when opening it in a web browser, for example by using cheatengine.

I'm not a Java pro, nor do I know how phonegap code is compiled for Android, but I'm wondering whether or not mobile games have this problem too. The code is run on the client so...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes most certainly. Applications like CheatEngine or the mobile equivalent work at very low level (assembly level) which all languages are ultimately compiled into therefore they are all equally as hackable.